# One metric second equals how many normal seconds?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, time, unit-conversion

I'm attempting to study for an exam on Friday and to do so I'm doing some practice problems - I got to this problem and for the life of me I can't figure out how to approach it.  The problem is as follows:

> Metric time is defined so that one day equals 10 hours, one hour equals 100 minutes, and one minutes equals 100 seconds.  One metric second equals how many normal seconds?

Given the information I have, how would I even solve this? It seems like an extremely basic problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

In a 24 hour day there are 24 * 60 * 60 = 86,400 normal seconds.

In a Metric day there are 10 * 100 * 100 = 100,000  metric seconds.

Both days measure the same revolution of the earth, so if you divide the total metric seconds in one day by the total normal seconds in one day, you will find a ratio that you should understand.

Comment: @JohnForkosh : Yes, you are right.  I re-worded it to be more of a clue and less of an answer.

Comment: Thanks for this regardless, I was staring at the problem completely lost (I flipped through the book and googled similar problems and couldn't find a thing that could help) - truthfully the last bit (after the calculations) was all I really needed - I just couldn't figure out how to relate an actual day with a metric day